# Convert UTC time into local time using python

Tags: python, django

i want to convert UTC time into user's browser time. 
i have tried a loat but its display me system time only. 
working with django application. can anybudy help me out.

```
    import pytz
    from tzlocal import get_localzone
    def utc_to_local(utc_dt):#utc_dt that is UTC time
        local_tz = get_localzone()
        print local_tz #that is display system timezone inplace of USER's timezone
```

I have tried with below code.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
utc = datetime.strptime(str(utc_dt)[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
return time.mktime(utc_dt.timetuple()) * 1000
```

convert utc time into second and then using javascript need to make it localtime. but conversion value not accurate and its display me wrong date.

Javascript code.

```
//1449206930000 #Seconds when above code run
//1449226703.79 #that is correct >> time.time() in python = 1449226703.79

#below code give perfact output
var date = new Date(parseInt(1449226703.79, 10) * 1000);
console.log(date);

#below code not working 
var date = new Date(parseInt(1449206930000, 10) * 1000);
console.log(date);
```

Regards

Comment: Can you show any code that you have tried?

Comment: i have edited question. looking forward to hearing from you soon

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the users timezone first, to convert time in there local timezone.

There are two ways to do it.

1) Pass simply UNIX-timestamp then use a Javascript to convert it in human readable time on the browser [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) can help you with that.

```
function human_time(unixtime, tz) {
    var t=moment.unix(unixtime);
    return t.tz(tz).format('DD/MM/YY HH:mm:ss');
}
```

2) [Use IP address or HTTP headers to detect the user location](https://github.com/Kami/django-visitor-information-middleware/) and then use [pytz](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/) to convert your time in users system timezone instead of your own django/server timezone.

```
def get_user_timezone(request):
    return request.visitor.location.timezone

def human_time(dt, tz="Asia/Kolkata"):
    try:
        tz = pytz.timezone(tz)
    except:
        tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
    dt = dt.astimezone(tz)
    return dt.strftime(r'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

 def view_get_local_time(request):
     tz = get_user_timezone(request) #detect user timezone, base on IP
     text = human_time(timezone.now(), tz) #convert server-time to detected timezone
     return HttpResponse(text)
```

**Note: First method is the most preferable method.**

Answer (score 0):

```
import time, calendar
import datetime
utc = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(timezone_rt)[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
return time.mktime(time.localtime(calendar.timegm(utc.timetuple()))) #convert utc time into second that correct output like function time.time()
```

Thanks for help.